# Search -> Find in Files; 11g R2 (11.1.2.3.0) - How to find strings that contain an underscore?

Tags: ide, jdeveloper

I am working on a Java MVC app, and jdeveloper is the office-mandated IDE that I am using.  All I want to do is search for strings (not the data type "string", just a string of characters) that contain underscores (for example, table names or field names like "TABLE_NAME" or "FIELD_NAME").  Unfortunately, it appears that the underscores are not taken into the search (if I search for FIELD_NAME it will return no results, even though I know that the string appears in the code numerous times).  Is there a way for me to search for something like FIELD_NAME in this version of jdeveloper?

11g R2 (11.1.2.3.0)

Comment: they're just files, right? There's nothing magical about jdev that you couldn't simply find using whatever OS you're using, like Windows desktop search, Unix grep, or OSX Finder.  Is there something you're trying to use jdev to DO with those results? If not, you're arbitrarily tying you're hands behind your back.  It's just a tool, after all...

Comment: Yeah, it looks like this is what I'll have to do.  I have to index the directory in Windows in order to search within the files, which takes a little while.  But it does end up returning the files that contain what I'm searching for.  I would have preferred an option within jdev, since that can bring me directly to each line of code, but this will have to do.  Thanks!

Comment: I come from more of a Unix background, so I honestly would suggest that you download a tool like [the_platinum_searcher](https://github.com/monochromegane/the_platinum_searcher), which was written in Go, so it's cross-platform compatible.  You'll have to get your hands a bit dirty with the command-line, but it's not as bad as it seems.

Comment: Cool, I'll look into it, thanks for the info!

Answer (score 1):

Like Nick says in the comment, this should just work.
Possibly you have messed with some setting in the Search popup.
[image]

1. Make sure you are searching on the correct file types
2. Make sure you are searching in the correct Application or project
3. Be sure to check the option menu at the bottom and set (your) correct settings

Comment: This doesn't work.  If it did I wouldn't be here in the first place.